# Expected value and sum of independent variables.

Tags: probability, means

EDIT: I've found my mistake. Flipped around the values because in my head I had them tails up at the start.. Not sure what to do with the question now...

> On a table there are three coins in a row, all heads side up. On each turn Lilach flips one coin. The left one with probability $1/2$, the middle $1/3$ and the right one with probability $1/6$, independently of other turns. Denote by $X_{n}$ the number of heads facing up after $n$ turns. Calculate the expected value of $X_{3}$.

Using the fact that expected value is a linear function, and a fact proven earlier that if $X\sim \rm{bin}(n,p)$ is a random variable, then $$P(X\text { is even})=\frac{1}{2}(1+(1-2p)^n)$$ I arrived at the following solution:

---

Letting $Y_{n,i}$ be a random variable equal to the number times coin $i$ was flipped during the first $n$ turns. Then for each $1\leq i\leq3$, $Y_{n,i}\sim{\rm Bin}\left(n,p_{i}\right)$ (where $p_{i}$ is the probability of coin $i$ being flipped, from left to right).

Now denoting by $A_{n,i}$ the random variable equal $1$ if coin $i$ is face up and $0$ if it's face down after $n$ flips, we have that $$P\left\{ A_{n,i}=1\right\} =\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(1-2p_{i}\right)^{n}\right)$$
and similarly
$$E\left[A_{n,i}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(1-2p_{i}\right)^{n}\right)$$

But $X_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}A_{n,i}$, thus $$E\left[X_{n}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{3}E\left[A_{n,i}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(1-1\right)^{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}\right)$$

or

$$E\left[X_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\frac{1+2^{n}}{3^{n}}\right)$$

Setting $n=3$ we get

$$E\left[X_{3}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left(3+\frac{1+8}{27}\right)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{10}{6}$$

---

The problem is that this breaks down for $n=1$, as $P\{X_1=1\}=1$, but the expected value I get from the formula is $2$, and I'm not sure where exactly it broke down.
I'm pretty certain that I can say that

$$X_n=\sum_i=1^3 A_{n,i}$$

it doesn't tell me much on the distribution of $X_n$ as these variables are dependent, but when looking at expected value the linearity should work even when the variables are indeed dependent, shouldn't it? So where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it using Markov Chain.  I am not sure about the formula that you have used and how you got it.  If you know Markov Chain, you shall be able to follow the solution easily. I have given the hand-written image and the computation image for your perusal.  Goodluck
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit

[image]

Based on Dr Scott's advice, I have modeled it as eight states and the transition matrix is much easier to draw and the expected number of heads given the intial state to be HHH is $\boxed{2}$

Comment: We have not reached Markov chains just yet, but I sure will come back to this answer once we do.
The formula can be reached by induction on $n$, considering the case with $n-1$ elements, with it being either even or odd, and adding the probability of success or failure accordingly.

Comment: You are welcome!!.  Which school do you go to?

Comment: Tel Aviv university.

Comment: You can model it as a Markov chain, but you need to keep track of $8$ states, not $4$: HHH, HHT, HTH, THH, HTT, THT, TTH, and TTT. That is, you can’t combine states with the same number of heads. The probability of a transition from one head to no heads, for instance, depends on the distribution of time spent in the states HTT, THT, and TTH; if this is uniform, then the probability is $\frac16$, but if not, it isn’t, and you don’t know ahead of time what it is.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, This is exactly what has been nagging me for a long time since I posted the solution.  If we did eight states, then it is one less worry of assumming things to be equally likely.  Let me try with eight states and see what answer I get.

Comment: Please take a look at the edit and see @Brian M. Scott 's comments and that of mine.  The expected number of heads after three turns with starting state of all heads up is exactly 2.