# Expected number of heads in 3 different coins after 3 flips

Tags: probability, proof-verification, expectation

Three coins are set on a table all showing Heads. Each turn one flips
one of them independently with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ for
the 1st coin, $\frac{1}{3}$ for the 2nd coin and $\frac{1}{6}$ for
the 3rd coin. Let $X_{n}$ be the number of Heads showing after $n$ turns. What
is the expected value of $X_{3}?$

My attempt:

Given these, I realized the only values $X_{3}$ can get are $0$ and
$2$, so I tried to calculate $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{3}=k\right)$
for $k\in\left\{ 0,2\right\} $:

- $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{3}=0\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\text{All coins got flipped}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$
- $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{3}=2\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\text{One of the coins got flipped twice}\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\biguplus_{i=1}^{3}\text{Coin } i \text{ got flipped twice}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{2}=\frac{7}{18}$

Therefore:

$$
\mathbb{E}X_{3}=\sum_{x\in\text{supp}\mu_{X_{3}}}x\cdot\mathbb{P}\left(X_{3}=x\right)=2\cdot\frac{7}{18}=\frac{7}{9}
$$
Where $\mu_{X_{3}}$ is the distribution function of $X_{3}$.

Now one thing that bothers me here is that
$$
\sum_{x\in\text{supp}\mu_{X_{3}}}\mu_{X_{3}}(x)\neq1
$$

So i'm thinking maybe I did something wrong with the calculations*

Any ideas?

Comment: Flip some coin three times and $X_3=3$?

Comment: Duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772920/expected-value-and-sum-of-independent-variables/1774092#1774092, Solved by me.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Flipping a coin three times, or any odd number of times, will turn it to Tails

Comment: @SatishRamanathan Well unfortunately i'm not familiar with Markov Chain, and I truly doubt it is what i'm suppose to use here. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability that all coins are flipped is: $$3!\times\frac12\times\frac13\times\frac16=\frac1{6}$$

Observe that $\frac12\times\frac13\times\frac16$ can e.g. be recognized as the probability that at first the first coin is flipped, then the second and at last the third. But there are $3!$ equiprobable orders leading to the same result.

So $P(X_3=0)=\frac16$.

Further it is clear $\{X_3=2\}$ is exactly the event that not all coins are flipped (if not all coins are flipped then it is inevitable that we end up with exactly two heads).

So $P(X_3=2)=1-\frac16=\frac56$.

That leads to: $$\mathbb EX_3=\frac16\times 0+\frac56\times 2=\frac53$$

---

edit:

Finding $P(X_3=2)$ by brute force gives:

$P(X_3=2)=3\times[\frac12\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)+\frac13\frac13(\frac12+\frac16)+\frac16\frac16(\frac12+\frac13)]+\frac12\frac12\frac12+\frac13\frac13\frac13+\frac16\frac16\frac16$

I haven't checked yet whether that indeed equals $\frac56$ .

Feel welcome to do and ring the alarm bells if it does not.

Comment: I see, and how would you describe the events under $\left\{ X_{3}=2\right\} $ that lead $\text{P}\left(X_{3}=2\right)$ to be $\frac{5}{6}$?

Comment: If you don't use the complementation rule (which is very handy here) then there are quite some cases to look after. E.g. the probability that the first coin is flipped twice is $3\times\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)$. We have 112,113,121,131,211,311 as possibilities. likewise you must calculate the probabilities that the second coin is flipped twice and that the third coin is flipped twice. Then you are not ready yet. You must calculate the probabilities that the first coin is flipped $3$ times, and the same for the other two coins.

Comment: What does $3\times\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)$ stand for? or more specifically,  $\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a factor. It should be $3\times\frac12\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)$. The probability of 112 (standing for  2 flips of the first followed by a flip of the second) is $\frac12\frac12\frac13$. There are $6$ terms like that and addition gives $3\times\frac12\frac12(\frac13+\frac16)$.

Comment: It is good to know *how* to find $P(X_3=2)$ as a summation of probabilities, but I also like the fact that I don't really need that here.